# Trouble matching the vibrant background of a Yosemite NSMenuItem containing a custom view

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks, nstextfield, osx-yosemite

I am attempting to add a custom view to an NSMenuItem in the OS X 10.10 Yosemite menu bar.

The custom view is simply an NSView background with an NSTextField “label”.

The problem is that the background NSView is given Yosemite-style vibrancy/transparency when added to the menu. The NSTextfield label is not.

[image: Background colors do not match]

Through the use of `NSRectFillUsingOperation` I've gotten this to look good for *some* background colors in Yosemite. But others continue to not match. When it is working, after manually "highlighting" the view, the original colors change and no longer match. I can dig up some example code for this if needed.

Then, when it is looking somewhat good in Yosemite, it looks terrible in 10.9 Mavericks.

I've also tried setting the `wantsLayer` property to YES to turn the view into a CALayer-backed view. This creates other issues such as text not anti-aliasing correctly against a clear background.

My Question:

How do I display a label on top of a NSMenuItem custom view? The label's background must exactly match the view's background. Solution must work in Yosemite and Mavericks.

Example code below:

```
self.statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]
statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
[self.statusItem setTitle:@"TEST"];
[self.statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
[self.statusItem setEnabled:YES];
[self.statusItem setTarget:self];

NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
[menu addItemWithTitle:@"Disabled menu item" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
[menu addItemWithTitle:@"Enabled menu item" action:@selector(enabled) keyEquivalent:@""];

NSTextField *label = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(30, 20, 50, 20)];
label.stringValue = @"label";
label.editable = NO;
label.bordered = NO;
label.backgroundColor = [NSColor blueColor];
//label.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];


PKMenuItemView *view = [[PKMenuItemView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 50)];
[view addSubview:label];

NSMenuItem *viewMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
[viewMenuItem setView:view];
[menu addItem:viewMenuItem];

self.statusItem.menu = menu;
```

I've subclassed the NSView to override `drawRect:` and draw a colored background:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    [[NSColor blueColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
    //NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeSourceOver);
}
```

Comment: could you make the background of the label transparent?

Comment: It's not as simple as giving the label a `clearColor` background. This leads to some combination of issues: blurry label text, a background that is *not* actually clear, or a fully transparent background that shows through to the desktop in Mavericks.

Comment: ah yeah sorry for giving an obvious suggestion.  that was the best I could contribute without doing deep research

Comment: Check the `_viewHandlesEvents` answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865236/how-to-flash-a-custom-nsmenuitem-view-after-selection

Comment: > FB6143600 - Enable easy VEV backgrounds for NSMenuItems with custom views

Answer (score 8):

It is surely kinda hack, but it worked for me.
Try adding an NSImageView with empty image to your custom view. Image view must be occupy the whole view.

[image: Using an NSImageView]

Comment: Interesting, I will test this out. Are you hitting the same issue in your app?

Comment: I have very similar issue with NSMenu and custom menu item views in my app on Yosemite. I'm using layer backed custom views, setting `self.layer.backgroundColor = [[CGColor clearColor] CGColor];`

Comment: Didn't finish it accidentally... My view contains small image view and ordinary NSTextFiled. I want highlight menu item on mouse over, so I added tracking area and setting `self.layer.backgroundColor = self.highlightBGColor` on mouseDown. Menu gets highlighted, but images are drawn with white background, though they are all transparent. When background color is set back to clear color, images are drawn OK again. Got no idea how to fix it.

Comment: This worked, thank you! Also wanted to clarify that "empty image" means you don't need to set an image. Just have the NSImageView as the first subview and set it to fill the parent view.

Comment: Although this looks much better than not using an NSImageView, it isn't quite the same as other menu items because it doesn't have any translucency. It would be nice if someone knew how to match it to that style.

Answer (score 5):

I think I have less "hackish" solution. It's indeed caused by the new NSVisualEffectView and Vibrancy stuff in Yosemite. I learned that there are quite complex rules how views are drawn when they're subviews of NSVisualEffectView. It was discussed on WWDC 2014 in session 220 - [Adopting Advanced Features of the New UI of OS X Yosemite](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/). I recommend you to watch this session video to get comprehensive explanation.

Shortly, it seems that your problem may be caused by colors you use. There are two new system colors - `[NSColor labelColor]` and `[NSColor secondaryLabelColor]`. These two are automatically adjusted when drawn inside NSVisualEffectView. Also, your custom view should support Vibrancy effect. This is done by overriding `- (BOOL)allowsVibrancy` method and returning YES.

Please check the session video mentioned above or download session slides in PDF to get precise information. This stuff is discussed from slide 124 in PDF and near the middle of the video.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there are currently several problems in Yosemite. As [Matthes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27448397/1016508) already mentioned, you can use `labelColor()` and `secondaryLabelColor()`. Using those colors do not cause the label to draw the strange background you are seeing.

However, `labelColor()` only works fine for VibrantDark because there the label color is white when a NSMenuItem is both highlighted and when not highlighted. With VibrantLight the `labelColor` is black and is therefore very difficult to read on on top of the blue highlight.

For the highlight color of the custom view of your NSMenuItem one might think that you should use `selectedMenuItemColor()` given its name. The problem with this is that the color doesn't actually match the menu highlight color that you see in NSMenuItems without a custom view. The color is completely wrong for both VibrantLight and VibrantDark.

Tl;dr: So how can you create a custom NSMenuItem that uses the exact same text color and highlight color? You can't. You should use `labelColor()` and `selectedMenuItemColor()` but the former only works correctly for VibrantDark, and the latter doesn't match at all.

I really hope I am wrong because I am trying to achieve the same thing :(

Edit: [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/337333/CustomNSMenuItem.zip) is an example project if people want to have a look.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I believe I tried `labelColor` and `selectedMenuItemColor` but had the same issues in light/dark mode. Very annoying issue, as I think I have it figured out but then switch to my Mavericks computer or light/dark mode and it's all wrong again.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `backgroundStyle` for the text field's cell when the menu item is selected to see if that causes the label color to invert?

Comment: I just tried all `backgroundStyle` values and none of them helped.

Comment: @iMaddin Thanks for the sample project. Like you said, unfortunately all of the options have some kind of problem...

Answer (score 4):

Response from a Apple Developer Technical Support ticket I opened in 2015:

> #### Re: DTS Auto-Ack - Vibrant background and highlighting of Custom View NSMenuItems
>
> This is a difficult problem to tackle, especially in light of the fact that menu selection drawing was not intended for menu items with custom views, and menu selection drawing (colors, etc.) may change in the future.  This is why we ask you to file bug reports so that menu selection will be honored with custom views, if asked for, so that future changes to OS X won’t require developers to continually maintain their code to match future color appearances.
>
> The “Application Menu and Pop-up List Programming Topics” says this:
>
> > Views in Menu Items -
> >
> > “A menu item with a view does not draw its title, state, font, or other standard drawing attributes, and assigns drawing responsibility entirely to the view. Keyboard equivalents and type-select continue to use the key equivalent and title as normal.”
>
> Since all drawing is up to the developer, custom views in menu items aren’t necessarily supposed to draw “selected”.
>
> The APIs to obtain the right selection color is obviously not doing what it’s supposed to, hence the request to file a bug report.  I wish we could offer more concrete solutions to the problem but a workaround offered today may not hold up tomorrow and we don’t want to set a bad precedent on workarounds that are risky.  Apple apps have access to lower level private APIs that achieve their results.  We cannot offer you these solutions as they are private.
>
> If `selectedMenuItemColor()` does not match the menu highlight color with Vibrant light and dark, that’s a bug to be filed and to be fixed.
>
> Lastly, Apple recommends to use NSMenuItem’s APIs as much as possible to achieve what you want in menus.  The screenshots you included can likely be done without applying custom views.

Answer (score 3):

I've just discovered that `+[NSColor keyboardFocusIndicatorColor]` is the right color (on El Capitan at least), whereas the expected `selectedMenuItemColor` is by far too dark.

Comment: After further use, I realize it's not behaving exactly like the native menus, but it's close…

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't behave well with night mode.

Comment: This is very possible @yesthisisjoe! Did you find a better solution? I'm still very much looking for one myself! If you have something, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I ended up using an attributed string instead of a custom view. So no, not really

Comment: I ended up using an attributed string instead of a custom view. So no, not really

Answer (score 2):

Per AppKit engineers at WWDC, this doesn't really work with NSMenuItem. I added that answer to this question as well.

They suggested to instead use an `NSPopover` to create a faux-NSMenu attached to an NSStatusItem menu bar helper.

Using code similar to the below results in vibrant background selection:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let visualEffectView = NSVisualEffectView()

    visualEffectView.material = .selection
    // .menu or .popover for the non-selected background.

    visualEffectView.state = .active
    visualEffectView.blendingMode = .behindWindow
    visualEffectView.isEmphasized = true

    let label = NSTextField(labelWithString: "Hello, world!")
    label.cell?.backgroundStyle = .emphasized
    visualEffectView.addSubview(label)
    visualEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    label.setFrameOrigin(.zero)
    view.addSubview(visualEffectView)
}
```

[image: Vibrant Window Background]

Answer (score 0):

At the WWDC 2019 AppKit Lab I worked through this issue with engineers from the AppKit team.

They were surprised that it did not work by default, and encouraged me to file (more) radars:

> FB6143574 - Expose private API for NSMenuItem `_viewHandlesEvents`

They were aware of a private API `_viewHandlesEvents` on NSMenuItem.

```
// VibrantMenuBar-Bridging-Header.h

#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface NSMenuItem ()

@property (setter=_setViewHandlesEvents:) BOOL _viewHandlesEvents;

@end
```

Set `viewHandlesEvents` to `false` and the background of the custom view in the NSMenuItem will be selected and appear (somewhat) as expected.

There are still issues with how labels and other subviews react to the selection. Text View text is not properly changing color.

```
let menuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
menuItem.view = label
menuItem._viewHandlesEvents = false
```

[image: NSMenuItemView with <code>_viewHandlesEvents</code> set to false]

There are some other references to `_viewHandlesEvents` on the internet:

- [How to flash a custom NSMenuItem view after selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865236/how-to-flash-a-custom-nsmenuitem-view-after-selection/12080307)