# Custom View in NSMenuItem does not highlight correctly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsmenuitem

I try to use a custom view for a `NSMenuitem`, which works. Unfortunately, I have some difficulties with the *highlighting* (mouseover). I already followed the instructions in other threads to implement `drawRect:` in my `NSView` subclass to do the blue *highlighting* manually. This seems to work, but the highlighting color is not correct. It appears too dark compared to regular menu items and interestingly the `subviews` of my custom view use the correct *highlighting* color (see screenshot).
Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

My current `drawRect:` method in the `NSView` subclass looks like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    BOOL isHighlighted = [[self enclosingMenuItem] isHighlighted];
    if (isHighlighted)
    {
        [[NSColor selectedMenuItemColor] setFill];
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect);

        [self.profileNameView setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
        [self.securedIPView setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
        [self.separatorView setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
        [self.connectionTimeView setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.profileNameView setTextColor:[NSColor controlTextColor]];
        [self.securedIPView setTextColor:[NSColor disabledControlTextColor]];
        [self.separatorView setTextColor:[NSColor disabledControlTextColor]];
        [self.connectionTimeView setTextColor:[NSColor disabledControlTextColor]];
    }
}
```

The resulting highlighting looks like:

[image]

Comment: This does not help, because then there is no highlighting at all...

Comment: The problem is related to the one described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851306/trouble-matching-the-vibrant-background-of-a-yosemite-nsmenuitem-containing-a-cu

Somehow the custom view does not correctly adapt to the menu's vibrant drawing in Yosemite.

Comment: Please try this color [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:.0705 green:0.3755 blue:0.9529 alpha:1.0]

Comment: Hey @FabianJäger, I found that in the latest Shimo the highlight looks really good. Can you share what you’ve done? Thank you!